# Navbar shows and hide menu in just one click, next click do nothing

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using `zerif-lite` theme for one of my projects. In this project on smaller screens the when I click on a toggled menu, it shows up but very quickly automatically hides itself again. My website can be found [here](http://optimumccl.com/)
Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following code to your css file after bootstrap.css:

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: is it online? as I cannot see css changed. I've tried this on "Elements console" in Chrome and it worked...

Comment: Is it online mean? Sorry i cant get what you mean

Comment: Oh sorry i do it in 'localhost'

Comment: Thanks bro it worked. But wont this cause problem in another portion of my site??

Comment: only if your website uses somewhere class .in within the navbar-collapse class. Otherwise you should be ok

Comment: Oh then there is no chance of that.